# 8085 μp; Why does Read cycle take 3 T-states and not 2?

Tags: microcontroller, microprocessor, computer-architecture, 8085

In the text I'm following, [R.S.Gaonkar](https://www.amazon.in/Books-Ramesh-Gaonkar/s?rh=n%3A976389031%2Cp_27%3ARamesh%20Gaonkar) it's explained that,

- During T1, address in Program Counter(PC) is latched onto the Memory Address Register(MAR),
- During the falling edge of T2 \$\overline{MEMR}\$ becomes active, and during the rising edge, contents in the Memory Data Register is **placed on the bus** \$^\dagger\$
- During T3, contents in the bus is latched on to the accumulator.

\$^\dagger\$ **My question is**, during the rising edge of T2, why is the MDR not directly latched onto the accumulator, but takes another T-state to latch it on?

Comment: That's the way it is.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič :( Alright, but it could save an entire T-State (someone would've definitely thought about this, cause there has to be a reason for extending the process to an entire T-State, else we could potentially save huge amounts of time, but that's not the case)

Comment: Is it because the 8085 has a multiplexed address bus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "extra" T state is designed into the cycle in order to give the external memory sufficient time to respond. Remember, when this chip was designed, the memory chips used the same basic technology as the processor, and were just as slow, plus additional time was required for external address decoding and bus buffering.

The designers wanted to make it easy to put together a "minimal" system without requiring external logic to generate wait states.

---

Here are the details of the read cycle, from the [datasheet](https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/52062.pdf), on page 1-25.

[image: read cycle timing diagram]

Keep in mind that t<sub>CYC</sub> is 320 ns (3 MHz, 8085AH), but could be as short as 167 ns (6 MHz, 8085AH-1).

t<sub>AD</sub> is the total memory access time from the CPU's point of view, from the time the address is stable to when the data must be valid. It is given as 575 ns for the 8085AH. If you shaved off a T cycle, this would drop to just 255 ns.

As I said, this is from the CPU's point of view — the address lines become valid *at the pins of the CPU* and the data must be valid *at the pins of the CPU*. This total time must include the time for the address signals to propagate through address buffers, address decoders and possibly across some sort of system backplane before it gets to the pins of the actual RAM chip. This is the point at which the RAM read cycle begins — t<sub>AA</sub> is the time from when the address is valid *at the pins of the RAM chip* to when its data outputs are valid, and this is usually the slowest parameter on the chip.

Then, when the data becomes valid *at the pins of the RAM chip*, it must still propagate through one or more bus buffers (and another trip across the backplane) before it gets back to the CPU itself.

All of that overhead could easily add up to something on the order of 200 ns. With a 2 T-state cycle, that would leave only 55 ns for the RAM chip access time. With a 3 T-state cycle, you get more like 375 ns, which is a much more reasonable value for the chips available at that time.

Comment: I gave some thought about this, and got a naive doubt, how can a memory be slow, I mean, wire transmit voltages and currents, why would that be slow? Doesn't that depend on our clock speed ? And what does bus buffering mean? I mean, I don't get the meaning of that phrase, like... as an action.

Comment: Memory chips are circuits, just like the processor.  So, they take time to react.

Comment: The processor pins were not strong enough to drive logic signals out to a number of memory chips all wired in parallel, or to drive a physically long wires.  So for all but the smallest boards, you needed buffers (i.e., 74HC244) to increase the drive.  Those buffers added delay.

Comment: @AravindhVasu how can a CPU be slow?

Comment: @user253751 what do you mean?

Comment: @AravindhVasu memory can be slow in the same way CPUs can be